# Is it correct to say "so it's hard for me to make a schedule"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

I have been swamped with work but I have to make time for some event. I was trying to express the point that my schedule is really full and it's hard for me to make some time for it. I wonder if the following sentence is natural and correct:

> it's hard for me to make a schedule

Or is there any other better ways to say it

Comment: "11 Jul 1993 — It's hard for me to make a schedule. Like Christmas morning. I'm just sitting here thinking who I am. " New York Times

Comment: Which parts of the sentence are you unsure about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common mistake for some English learners to use the word "schedule" to mean "a scheduled time". A schedule is a *timetable of several events*, like an events calendar, a travel itinerary, or the timeline of all events for a conference. It is not the date and time for just one specific event.

So while your sentence is grammatically correct and natural, it means:

> It's hard for me to create a timetable of several events

It does *not* mean that it's hard for you to find time for one event.

Comment: "It's hard for me to fit it in [to my schedule]."

Answer (score 0):

It's probably understandable, given sufficient context, but a better way to state the situation would be to say:

*"It's hard for me to find space to add  to my schedule."*